# How do I make create a socket to Stratum using a script?

Tags: bash, shell, sockets, curl, stratum

I'm trying to understand teh stratum protocol and would like to try the initial step of connecting to a stratum pool.  I crated an account on SlushPool and would like to make a connection using some kind of script (I figured bash).  So I tried this

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id": 1, "method": "mining.subscribe", "params": []}\n' http://stratum.slushpool.com:3333
```

but I get the reply

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

So I would seem to be doing something wrong given the expected result should be something like

```
{"id": 1, "result": [["mining.notify", "ae6812eb4cd7735a302a8a9dd95cf71f"], "08000002", 4], "error": null}\n
```

as described here -- https://github.com/ctubio/php-proxy-stratum/wiki/Stratum-Mining-Protocol .  WHat's a simple way I can try out a stratum connection using a bash-compatible script?

Answer (score 2):

Use netcat instead.

```
nc <address> <port number>
```

After you connect paste in the

```
{"id": 1, "method": "mining.subscribe", "params": []}
```

Press enter, and the server should send a response. The problem is that `curl` is doing an http request, whereas stratum is based on a pure JSON api.